# On duplicate key with hstore merge using jooq

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Currently, I'm trying to implement the following sql query in jooq:

```
INSERT INTO table as t (id, hstore_data) 
VALUES ('test', '"key1" => "val1"') 
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE SET hstore_data = add(t.hstore_data, '"keyX" => "valX"');
```

*add()* is a custom function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add(hstore, hstore) RETURNS hstore
AS 'select $1 || $2;'
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

So far, I managed to get this up and running:

```
return DSL.using(configuration)
            .insertInto(TABLE)
            .columns(TABLE.ID, TABLE.HSTORE_DATA)
            .values(table.getId(), table.getHstoreData())
            .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
            .set(TABLE.HSTORE_DATA,
                            merge(
                                    DSL.using(configuration).select(TABLE.HSTORE_DATA).from(TABLE).where(TABLE.ID.eq(table.getId())).fetchAnyInto(HashMap.class)
                                    , table.getHstoreData()

                            )
                    )
            .execute();
```

*merge()* is a simple JAVA function merging two maps.

This approach works. However, I'd like to do all the processing on the database server as the first query suggests.

I tried to use the routine that jooq generates for *add()*. But it seems like jooq does not use the hstore binding. The binding is defined in the ConfigGenerator as follows:

```
types.add(new ForcedType()
            .withUserType("java.util.Map<String, String>")
            .withBinding("HStoreStringBinding")
            .withIncludeExpression(".*_data")
            .withIncludeTypes(".*"));
types.add(new ForcedType()
            .withUserType("java.util.Map<String, Long>")
            .withBinding("HStoreLongBinding")
            .withIncludeExpression(".*_counts")
            .withIncludeTypes(".*"));
```

The binding works for hstores, just not for the custom function.

1. Are there more clever approaches?
2. What might be the reason for add() not being correctly typed?
3. How can I tell jooq to use the original value in the merge as I do in the raw SQL query with t.hstore_data?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't actually need to define your own `add()` function. You can simply use `hs_concat()` which is the implementation of the `||` operator for hstore.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name indeed, I once thought about trying that and forgot about it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What might be the reason for add() not being correctly typed?

Try naming your function parameters, otherwise you cannot match them with the `includeExpression` property. To match the return value of the function, use the function name itself as an `includeExpression`. Of course, you could just leave the property away, and match all `hstore` types with a more generic binding:

```java
types.add(new ForcedType()
            .withUserType("java.util.Map<String, String>")
            .withBinding("HStoreStringBinding")
            .withIncludeTypes("hstore"));
```

> How can I tell jooq to use the original value in the merge as I do in the raw SQL query with t.hstore_data?

Once code generation works, you just use your add function, just like in the SQL version of your statement:

```java
set(TABLE.HSTORE_DATA, Routines.add(TABLE.HSTORE_DATA, table.getHstoreData()))
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks! I just had to swap the order of the ForcedTypes as well
One more thing: when I apply your suggestion for the set(...) the parameters clash. TABLE.HSTORE_DATA is a Record whereas the function expects a map

Comment: @fabianski: *"I just had to swap the order of the ForcedTypes as well"* - The first match applies. *"TABLE.HSTORE_DATA is a Record"* - Why is it a record now? You had applied that first forced type for all `".*_data"` columns. Did you change that?

Comment: ah, yeah I must have changed something bc I wanted to try leaving away the property. However, that created errors since Map<String, Long> is necessary at some places.

So by _To match the return value of the function, use the function name itself as an includeExpression._ I understand to do something like                 `.withIncludeExpression(".*_data | add")`. Did you mean that? Because it still does not match the typing :(

Comment: @fabianski: `Map<String, String>` and `Map<String, Long>` are incompatible types in Java. This sounds like a new question with additional information why you needed `Map<String, Long>` in the first place.

Comment: Yeah you're right. At this place I do not need Map<String, Long>. But in other places, I store counts of different tags in an object. Using Map<String, Long> instead of Map<String, String> there eases some things. That's why I differ between *_data and *_counts

Comment: @fabianski: I see - I guess you'll have to create two `add` functions then, even if they do the same thing in PostgreSQL. `addData()` and `addLong()`. Or, you create a utility in Java that reproduces the concatenation without using any stored functions. I could show this in a new question.

Comment: okay. Just to double check: I won't need the add() method for <String, Long>, only for <String,String> hstore concatenations. Would that still require two add functions? 
Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @fabianski. "You don't need it. Does that require it?" - I guess you already answered your own question :)

Comment: haha, tru that :D
should I open another question about the aforementioned problem with `.withIncludeExpression(".*_data | add")` ?

Comment: @fabianski: I'll check that again tomorrow and will update my answer if anything is missing

Comment: okay so with a mwe I managed to get the binds working:                 .withIncludeExpression(".*_data.*") or                 .withIncludeExpression("functionName.*")
 does the trick. Seems like the function's name itself is not enough. 
Now it's only the parameters that are clashing as TABLE.HSTORE_DATA is a record. I will check that tomorrow and either get back to it here or post a new question.

Comment: I could not get rid of this clash and posted a follow up question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224353/datatypes-incompatible-when-using-sql-custom-routine-with-jooq