# Datatypes incompatible when using sql custom routine with jooq

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

While implementing an upsert that uses a custom-defined SQL function, I came across the following error:

```
[ERROR] /home/user/company/ahqjava/sql/src/main/java/com/company/project/sql/daos/ExampleDAO.java:[60,56] no suitable method found for mergeData(org.jooq.TableField<com.company.project.sql.jooq.tables.records.ExampleRecord,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>)[ERROR]     method com.company.project.sql.jooq.Routines.mergeData(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<com.company.project.sql.jooq.tables.records.ExampleRecord,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>> cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>)
[ERROR]     method com.company.project.sql.jooq.Routines.mergeData(org.jooq.Field<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>,org.jooq.Field<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Field<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>)
```

The custom SQL function merge_data() looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_data(left_data hstore, right_data hstore)
  RETURNS HSTORE AS $$
    SELECT (left_data || right_data)
     $$
   LANGUAGE SQL;
```

and this is the current jooq DSL

```
return DSL.using(configuration)
        .insertInto(EXAMPLE)
        .columns(EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE_ID, EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE_DATA)
        .values(EXAMPLE.getExampleId(), example.getExampleData())
        .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
        .set(EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE_DATA, Routines.mergeData(EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE_DATA, example.getExampleData())

        )
       .execute();
```

`Example example` is a POJO.

For the sake of completeness, this is the method I'm using to call the function:

```
    @Test
    public void upsertTestDifferentExampleData() {
        Example example = createExample();
        jooq.transaction(cfg -> {

            dao.upsert(example, cfg);

        });


    }
```

Can someone suggest an approach to get rid of this parameter clash?

Edit: 
Here's my forced type config

```
types.add(new ForcedType()
                .withUserType("java.util.Map<String, String>")
                .withBinding("HStoreStringBinding")
                .withIncludeExpression(".*_data.*")
                .withIncludeTypes(".*"));

        types.add(new ForcedType()
                .withUserType("java.util.Map<String, Long>")
                .withBinding("HStoreLongBinding")
                .withIncludeExpression(".*_counts")
                .withIncludeTypes(".*"));
```

Comment: what I figured so far is to create a custom unmapper `.set(EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE_DATA, Routines.mergeData(EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE_DATA,unmapper.unmap(example).field6()`
However, I do not like the approach and hope that there's another way to do this...

Comment: nevermind, while testing I noticed this does not actually use the value of the example object as jooq logs this:


`.set "example_data" = "public"."merge_data"(
      "left_data" := "public"."example"."example_data", 
      "right_data" := "public"."example"."example_data"
    )`